# html div divide cross vertically in four parts

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am stuck in create one design..
i want to divide div in four cross vertical line but i am not able to divide it in four part.
Please check attachment
i want a design like this..but i am able to divide div in only two part..
please help me for this..

```
<div class ="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3"><div>
```

i am try this but it is give me 4 straight vertical column

Thank you[image]

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show more what you issue is. Is it some issue with the grid your having or do you want help to make the vertical grid gutter?

Comment: i need a output like this and i am getting output like 4 straight vertical line..give me some time i will add link of fiddle

Comment: hi, I found a really good example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/jeradg/pen/AzpuG) with diagonal navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your problem is, you need to provide more information: i made you this, this has some information to achieve your goal ( i think ), *it is just an ugly example*.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper > span {
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    font-size: 8px;
}

.info {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 0px / 290px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-left: 2px #00ff00 solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 250px 50px 0 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px black;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

div.info:nth-last-child(3) {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300/nightlife/);
  right: 250px;
}

.info:nth-last-child(2) {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300/nature/);
  right: 100px;
}

.info:nth-last-child(1) {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300/fashion/);
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic lif</span>
  <div class="info">Nightlife</div>
  <div class="info">Nature</div>
  <div class="info">Fashion</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have try this code and make it with use of bootstrap..thank you so much.. for this help.. i really appreciate.. Thnks again

Comment: Yes, i know but as mentioned " this has some information to achieve your goal ( i think )". if you try more to explain what the problem is (image of what is wrong and what is the desire result) than i can defiantly help you.

Comment: actually i want to create this like in Bootstrap carousel..i will use your code to create effect like this.. Thank you

Comment: No thanks needed, if there is anything i can do to help, please feel free to tag me :)